# My sink is coming off the wall how do i fix it?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, sink, adhesive

[image]

It is coming off the wall and as you can see the wall looks to be broken down i am not sure how to fix it correctly please help.

Comment: Is there any supports for the front of sink going down to the floor?  It looks like it was just glued on instead of having proper bolts/screws into the wall.

Comment: Could you post a photo of the whole sink please. Are there logos or name on it